# Kolmogorov backward and forward equations for a discrete-time Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

I found Kolmogorov backward equations and forward equations for [diffusion processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_%28diffusion%29), and for [continuous time Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_equations_%28Markov_jump_process%29) in Wikipdia. I was wondering what Kolmogorov backward and forward equations are  like for a discrete-time Markov chain? Thanks!